# Implementing Cypress's Application Actions to Nuxt3

Tags: testing, cypress, e2e-testing, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

In this 2019 Cypress's [blog post](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/03/stop-using-page-objects-and-start-using-app-actions#application-actions) they recommend to move away from *Page objects* in favor of *Application Actions*. React is used in the post's example:

```js
// app.jsx code
var model = new app.TodoModel('react-todos');

if (window.Cypress) {
  window.model = model
}
```

I know nothing about React but it seems they pass the instance of the app in the global window variable

I'm wondering if at the time of this writings similar approche is possible with Nuxt3 and how the implementation would be.

A repo of the Todo App example using the App Actions is available [here](https://github.com/bahmutov/test-todomvc-using-app-actions/tree/master)

on Nuxt official [doc](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/testing) about testing, the the e2e testing is just a: *We are working on it, stay tuned!*

Comment: IMO app actions only work well if the app has a central state like redux or pinia in the case of Vue. If you have lots of islands of state in various components as with React hooks or Vue compostion/setup, it becomes a much bigger job to expose them. WRT to Nuxt, it may not be possible because SSR means `window` is excluded from a lot of the code.